# Binary sequence that follows constraints

Tags: combinatorics, binary

Suppose I have a binary string of length $n$ with the only permissible characters $0$ and $1$. The string is supposed to follow the constraint that adjacent to every character must be a $0$, either to the left, or the right, or both.

I denote by $S_n$ the number of strings of length $n$ that follow the aforementioned criteria. How can I evaluate $S_n$ for somewhat larger values such as say $13$? Is a closed form expression possible for $S_n$?

**My work**

I couldn't make any progress on this, but it is clear that for the condition to follow for a string of length $n$, the $2$nd and $(n-1)$th digits must both be $0$. The evaluation becomes rather simple for smaller $n$ such as $S_3 = 3$, $S_4 = 4$, $S_5=4$, $S_6=9$ etc. But I am struggling to find any way to evaluate something like $S_{13}$.

Any help is  appreciated.

Comment: Note that a "good string" must look like $0^{a_1}10^{a_2}1\cdots 10^{a_k}$ where $a_1, a_k$ might be $0$ but the other $a_i$ are all at least $1$.  Thus, if you knew how many $1's$ there were, this is a simple Stars and Bars problem.  so, you can just sum over the possible number of $1's$.

Comment: Should say, I expect there is a better way to do this...but this method isn't all that difficult and it should at least give you a long list of computed values which will definitely help.

Comment: Correction:  The non-zero $a_i$ need to be at least $2$.  Still not a complicated count.

Comment: Just to add to @lulu 's comment (which is definitely a good approach to use), two other ideas for when you're not sure what to try on problems like these are 1) just write out and count some cases for small $n$; 2) look for a recursion. The three combined methods should let you conjecture and prove a formula

Comment: Note that every good word must either be $1$ followed by a good word, or $00$ followed by a good word.  However, while you can always prepend a $00$ to any good word, you can't always prepend a $1$.  This suggests that a double recursion might work (distinguish between the good words that start with $1$ and those that start with $0$).

Comment: Or you could say that $a_n$ is the number of good $n$-bit strings ending $\ldots00$ and $b_n$ the number ending $\ldots01$ and $c_n$ the number ending $\ldots10$ and $d_n$ the number ending $\ldots11$.  Clearly $d_n=0$ and for example $c_n=b_{n-1}+d_{n-1} = b_{n-1}$ and you can do something similar with $a_n=$ and $b_n$, noting that $S_n=a_n+b_n+c_n+d_n$.  This can be turned into a recurrence for $S_n$   which can be solved (or you could spot the pattern of the early values).

Comment: @sahaj how did you derive that $S_3=3$, because i count $000,100,010,001,101$ ?

Comment: I didn’t count $010$ and $101$, since adjacent to the $0$s there is no $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find these values by hand you can use the concept of dynamic programming.

Lets first denote the following expressions:

$S_{n, 0}$ - number of valid sequences of length $n$ starting with $0$
$S_{n, 1}$ - number of valid sequences of length $n$ starting with $1$
$S_{n}$ - number of valid sequences of length $n$

Obviously $S_n = S_{n, 0} + S_{n, 1}$

Let's observe that any such sequence must have $0$ as the second digit.
If sequence of length $n$ begins with $1$ then the remaining part of the sequence must be valid sequence of length $n - 1$ and must begin with $0$. So:
$$S_{n, 1} = S_{n-1, 0}$$

Furthermore if sequence of length $n$ begins with $0$ then we can have two cases.

Case $1$: third digit of the sequence is equal to $0$
We can easily denote that the number of such sequences is equal to $S_{n-1, 0}$, becuase apart from starting $0$ the remainig part must form valid sequence of lentgh $n-1$ that starts with $0$.

Case $2$: third digit of the sequence is equal to $1$
We can observe that, this $1$ already has adjacent $0$ so we can say that remaining part of the sequence (apart from the first three digits) must form valid seqeunce of length $n-3$ and there are $S_{n-3}$ such sequences.

So we can denote:
$$S_{n, 0} = S_{n-1, 0} + S_{n-3}$$

If we now take everything together we will get:
$$S_n = S_{n, 0} + S_{n, 1} = S_{n-1, 0} + S_{n-1, 0} + S_{n-3} = 2S_{n-1, 0} + S_{n-3}$$

To efficiently calculate those values we can store these results in a table:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
n & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
\hline
S_{n, 0} & 2 & 2 & 3 & 6 & 10 & \color{red}{15}& \\
\hline
S_{n-2} & ? & ? & 3 & 4 & 5 & 9 & 16 & \color{green}{25}&\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
To fill up the table you have to first find the value of first row by adding values in previous column (here you get $10 + 5 = 15$) and then you can find the value in the second row by adding to previously achieved result value from the second last cell in the first row (here $15 + 10 = 25$). Notice that there is a shift applied for the values of $S_n$ beacuse now you can fill the table in more convenient way.